# "fetch" event listener not triggering in service worker for file upload via multipart/form-data post in Safari

Tags: javascript, forms, file-upload, safari, service-worker

I am running a multi-page app that uses a service worker to maintain authentication state across page loads by adding an Authentication header to all the same-origin fetches. The set up is pretty straightforward (very similar to [Adding a new header to a Request, while preserving the body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634641)) and seems to work well overall.

My service worker contains this:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  console.log("FETCH CALLED");
  // Check and compare origin, add Authentication header, etc...
  // I'm leaving the details out because in the problem case, it never gets here.
});
```

On the website, I have a simple form that takes a file upload from a button trigger, as follows:

```
<form action="update_logo" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" name="upload_data" id="logo-upload-chooser" 
         onchange="this.form.submit();" hidden="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="brand_key" value="12345">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload_file_type" value="image/*">
</form>
<script>
  $("#file-upload-button").click(function() {
    $("#logo-upload-chooser").trigger("click");
  });
</script>
```

On Chrome and Firefox, things work just fine.  When a file is chosen, the form is submitted, the fetch listener in the service worker is triggered, auth headers are added and verified on the server, the file gets uploaded, and all is well. But **on Safari, the fetch listener is never triggered**.

Interestingly, if I submit the form without adding a file, that works (though there is no upload, so it's not useful).  Or if change the enctype, that seems to works too, but then the file isn't readable.  It seems like any time I have a well-formed file upload post, the "fetch" event never gets triggered, and thus the service worker is never called.  And again this all works great on Chrome and Firefox, just not on Safari.

Is this a Safari bug?  Is there a workaround?  Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I just encountered the same problem. I didn't find much documentation online about it, and no workaround yet.

Answer (score 1):

I reported the issue on Safari here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187461
Don't hesitate to reply and tell you're annoyed by it.

There is a workaround proposed:
Transform your file input into a data/uri and remove the regular input file.
Doing so will let your POST request goes through the Service Worker.

```js
formData.delete('file');

// get it as blob adn readd it as regular post field
// NB: File has to be recreated on server side using _files[file][name] and _files[file][data] to work as it was a regular file upload
var file = form.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];

formData.append('_files[file][name]', file.name);

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
    formData.append('_files[file][data]', e.target.result);

    doFetch(id, form, formData);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

On server side, you'll have to do some additionnal work to transform the data/uri into a regular file.